# Retrofit How To Print Out Response JSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit and I want to get access to the JSON response that is returned from the server. Could someone please advise me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you only want to see the respones for debugging purpose just turn on debugging in retrofit and look at the log. It's something like:

```
restAdapter.setDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

If you need access to the direct response in code all of the time, you should be doing that at the httpclient level as it's basically bypassing the purpose of retrofit

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I updated the code snippet to use proper methods for logging out Retrofit. All of your answers are correct, so thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

To print the response object first change the callback object type to the generic Object type via `Callback<Object> cb`. Then in your success callback you can just log the object to print the Json formatted version to the console.

```
@Override
public void success(Object o, Response response) {
    Log.i("Tag", "Login data " + o.toString());
}
```

To print the request object you can use whatever Json library you use (here I'm using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) to serialize the request object to Json and log that to the console.

```
Log.i("Tag", "Request data " + new Gson().toJson(requestObject));
```

Comment: I'm getting this error, so it never gets into the success function and goes to the failed function. Any thoughts? com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Comment: Try using a list of Objects instead

Comment: I have tried that but still getting an error. Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817604/retrofit-convert-array-of-objects-to-gson-error/25819168#25819168

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use full power of Retrofit and keep the raw input for yourself (e.g. to save it in persistent cache), you can extend the *Converter*, e.g.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson) {
        @Override
        public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
            try {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[body.length()];
                body.in().read(buffer);
                body.in().reset();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ConversionException(e);
            }
            return super.fromBody(body, type);
        }
    })
    ...build();
ResponseInterface ri = restAdapter.create(ResponseInterface.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get response in string format  and then parse data using gson.
To get String response you can use CustomStringConverter by extending retrofit.converter.Converter or just get the inputstream from the response on success result.

```
public void success(Response r1, Response r2) {

    IntputStream in  = r1.getBody().in()
       //convert this inputstream to string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also log the result like this

```
mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getBaseUrl())
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) //Log the result
            .build();
```